# Score value of my node is not rising

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, network, peers, tor

I'm running Bitcoin Core 0.20.1 in Debian Buster.
I run the daemon behind Tor network.

My current settings are:

/etc/tor/torrc

> SOCKSPort 9005
> ControlPort 9501
> HiddenServiceDir/var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service
> HidenServicePort 8333
> 127.0.0.1:8333 HiddenServiceVersion 3

/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc (other than default that was already there):

> CookieAuthentication 1
> CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
> CookieAuthFile /run/tor/control.authcookie

~/.bitcoin.conf (just networking related settings here)

> proxy=127.0.0.1:9005
> bind=127.0.01
> listen=1
> externalip=my.onion.adress.onion <-- dummy, of course
> onlynet=onion
> port=8333
> torcontrol=127.0.0.1:9501
> onion=127.0.0.1:9005

With these settings, why isn't 'score' value from 'getnetworkinfo' command output not increasing with my node uptime?

Comment: Can you share the result for `getnetworkinfo` ?

Comment: @Prayank, I changed my bitcoin core configuration and I'm not using those settings anymore. I appreciate the reply and sorry I took this long to reply. If I try to setup bitcoin core again, manually behind tor, I'll come back to this thread. As of now, the score is rising but I'm not using Tor to control the service. It is being controlled by bitcoin core. Thank you!